# How can I replicate this UI pattern: click ListView item and expand below it?

Tags: android, listview, expandablelistview

For example, in the application Plume, when you click on a ListView item (a tweet), it expands beneath it to show some actions (reply, links, retweet, etc.). How can I replicate this behavior in my application? I want to be able to click a ListView item and then "expand" it with my own actions (for the item selected).

Screenshot example:

[image]

What is the UI design pattern being used here?

Comment: This might be a good start if you're looking to write it yourself. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

Comment: @ninetwozero so is it just an ExpandableListView? Is that the best way to approach it?

Answer (score 3):

You have to create it for yourself. You should create a custom adapter which extends `BaseExpandableListAdapter` and in `getChildView` you should put the buttons in a horizontal `LinearLayout` with `TextViews` and set the `TextView`'s `android:drawableTop` with the icons you want to use.

A very simple use of this layout:

```
<LinearLayout 
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="horizontal">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/replyText"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/someText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/otherText"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_margin="5dp"
            android:text="@string/app_name"
            android:drawableTop="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

</LinearLayout>
```

You can use your drawables and strings. It's just an approach.

Comment: This seems to be the right approach. I'll see if anyone else says anything about it before digging into it myself. Thanks for the answer!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if Plume uses this library but I've had success using [Android - SlideExplandableListView](https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView) for this functionality.

https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView